# How to convert my horizontal listview in vertical mode like in Disney+ app?

Tags: flutter, dart

```
:SliverToBoxAdapter(
        child: SizedBox(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              // ignore: prefer_const_constructors
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 210.0),
                // ignore: prefer_const_constructors
                child: Text(
                  "Great Personality",
                  // ignore: prefer_const_constructors
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    fontSize: 20.0,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Column(
                children: [
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: SizedBox(
                      height: 200,
                      child: ListView(
                        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                        children: [
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                            child: InkWell(
                              child: Container(
                                width: 120,
                                color: Colors.amber,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                            child: Container(
                              width: 120,
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                            child: Container(
                              width: 120,
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                            child: Container(
                              width: 120,
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                            child: Container(
                              width: 120,
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                            child: Container(
                              width: 120,
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

I want my UI to convert in vertical style whenever I  tap on the arrow button like in Disney App Homepage
from this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NI7Dn.jpg)
to this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uth5I.jpg)

Which Widget I should Use so that Whenever Someone clicks on the right arrow button, it navigate to another page, and whatever Container in horizontal listview gets converted to vertical mode?

Answer (score 0):

You might want a list view inside a list view

Here is an example code:

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
Widget horizontalList1 = new Container(
  margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20.0),
  height: 200.0,
  child: new ListView(
  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
  children: <Widget>[
    Container(width: 160.0, color: Colors.red,),
    Container(width: 160.0, color: Colors.orange,),
    Container(width: 160.0, color: Colors.pink,),
    Container(width: 160.0, color: Colors.yellow,),
  ],
)
);
Widget horizontalList2 = new Container(
    margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20.0),
    height: 200.0,
    child: new ListView(
  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
  children: <Widget>[
    Container(width: 160.0, color: Colors.blue,),
    Container(width: 160.0, color: Colors.green,),
    Container(width: 160.0, color: Colors.cyan,),
    Container(width: 160.0, color: Colors.black,),
  ],
)
);
return new Scaffold(
  appBar: new AppBar(
    title: new Text(widget.title),
  ),
  body: new Center(
    child: new Container(
      child: ListView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        children: <Widget>[
          horizontalList1,
          horizontalList2,
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
);
```

Here is the result:

[Horizontal List view inside list view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RTtJm.gif)